# To get like count betwwen two dates in MySql

Tags: mysql

Sir,
    The concept of my project is ,the logged user can upload three different photos  and the deatils are stored in b_photodetails table and the fields are`(id,photoid,student_id,userid,count,likes,subdate ) idas1,2,3...`ect photoid means the name of the store photo file userid and count is the the number of photoes uploaded ie 1,2 and 3anly.and likes is the total number of likes for each photos.And i Have another table like_master containing the like details and the fields are`(like_id,userid, liked_date)` ,the like id in this table is same as id in the `b_photodetails` table ,and the `liked_date` is the date in which the photo is liked.So i need to get the number of likes between two particular 
dates.Please help me to frame a query to solve this in MySQL.

For eg:If we click a like for where id=1,the likes in b_photodetails will be 1 and the  like_master table will be(like_id,userid, liked_date) (1,userid eg:sree,2014-01-28)

Comment: what you have tried? pls show us your query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't really know for sure what you are asking, but, here is my stab in the dark:

```
select sum(likes) from like_master where liked_date between 'date1' and 'date2';
```

or possibly

```
select sum(lm.likes)
from b_photodetails as b
right join like_master as lm
on b.userid = lm.userid
where lm.liked_date between 'date1' and 'date2';
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand much what you are asking but may be it is like this

```
Select b.*,(SELECT COUNT(like_id) from like WHERE b.id = like.photo_id) as total_likes FROM b.photodetails
```